# How do I remove empty space at the top (between name and education section) , in banking style resume, as shown in the picture?

Tags: moderncv, cv, vertical-spacing

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}     
\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{purple}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.915]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

\name{Name}{}
\phone[mobile]{ph}                 
\email{email@gmail.com}                              
\homepage{www.linkedin.com/in/profile}   

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Education}
\vspace{0pt}
\item{\cventry{Expected Graduation: June 2022}{Bachelors in engineering}{Name of the university}{location}{\textit{}}{}}
\vspace{1pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437730/reduce-vertical-space-above-recipient-name-address-in-moderncv-cover-letter?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You need to patch the command `\makehead` in file `moderncvheadiii.sty`. At the end it contains the code

```
    \flushmakeheaddetails}\fi}\\[2.5em]}
```

and `\\[2.5em]` is responsible for the white space you do not like. Use the following patch in your preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================
\patchcmd{\makehead}{\\[2.5em]}{\\[0em]}{}{} % <========================
```

Change the value `0em` for your needs ...

Please see the following complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{purple}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.915]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}


\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================
\patchcmd{\makehead}{\\[2.5em]}{\\[0em]}{}{} % <========================

\name{Name}{}
\phone[mobile]{ph}                 
\email{email@gmail.com}                              
\homepage{www.linkedin.com/in/profile}   

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Education}
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{itemize} % <=====================================================
\item \cventry{Expected Graduation: June 2022}{Bachelors in engineering}{Name of the university}{location}{\textit{}}{}
\end{itemize} % <=======================================================
\vspace{1pt}
\end{document}
```

You are using an `\item` without using `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` in your code. That gives an error messages I corrected with adding `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` to the MWE. Please see that command `\item` takes no parameter!

Now you have an paragraph going outside the rule as you can see in this screen shot:

[image: resulting pdf]

In my answer to question [moderncv extend hrule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392811/16550) you can find the code to correct this error.

Answer (score 0):

After `\maketitle` add the following line

```
\vspace{-40pt}
```

or change the number `-40` to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: If you think an answer is helpful, you may consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the up arrow next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓)